# reverse the color for heatmap colorbar

Tags: seaborn, heatmap

Is there a way to reverse the colorbar for heatmap for the cmap parameter?

For example,

```
sns.heatmap([List], cmap='RdBu') # I dont have an input yet so just wanted to try
```

example of output:

```
5 higher-higher-higher-red-ish
4 higher-higher-higher-red-ish
3 higher-higher-red-ish
2 higher-red-ish
1 red-ish
0 white-ish
-1 blue-ish
-2 higher-blue-ish
-3 higher-higher-blue-ish
-4 higher-higher-blue-ish
-5 higher-higher-blue-ish
```

Expected example of output:

```
5 higher-higher-higher-blue-ish
4 higher-higher-higher-blue-ish
3 higher-higher-blue-ish
2 higher-blue-ish
1 blue-ish
0 white-ish
-1 red-ish
-2 higher-red-ish
-3 higher-higher-red-ish
-4 higher-higher-red-ish
-5 higher-higher-red-ish
```

Sorry I dont have a better example.

Comment: try cmap = 'BuRd', if that doesn't work then just make your own

Comment: I tried it but it wont work. How can I make it?

Comment: Most colormaps have a reversed version. Just add "_r" to their name, as in `cmap='RdBu_r'`